# Notation of a vector of vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation

Does a "vector of vectors" exist, and how would one formulate such a thing?

I have a vector $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ that I would like to divide into 4 vectors of equal length to make notation easier lateron. I would like to use those parts in matrix multiplication later on, e.g.

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{b}_0 \mathbf{A} & \vec{b}_1 \mathbf{B} \\
\vec{b}_2 \mathbf{C} & \vec{b}_3 \mathbf{D}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\vec{b}_n \in \mathbb{R}^{\frac{N}{4}}$ is the $n$-th part of the original vector $\vec{a}$.

In the NumPy world, I would think of $\vec{b}$ as an $\mathbb{R}^{4 \times \frac{N}{4}}$ matrix and would extract the $n$-th row, but I don't think this would be possible or helpful here.

Comment: Your problem is purely notational. If we write "Suppose that $N$ is a multiple of $4$; Let $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}$, and write $\vec{a}=(\vec{b}_1,\vec{b}_2,\vec{b}_3,\vec{b}_4)$, where each $\vec{b}_n\in\mathbb{R}^{N/4}$", then it is pretty clear what we mean. I wouldn't talk about a "vector of vectors" because a vector is simply an element of a vector space

Comment: If $\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, and $4 \ | \ n$ (it means: $n$ is divisible by $4$), then here are four equal sized "subvectors" $\vec{a}^{(1)}=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{n/4})$, $\vec{a}^{(2)}=(a_{1+n/4},a_{2+n/4},\cdots,a_{n/2})$, $\vec{a}^{(3)}=(a_{1+n/2},a_{2+n/2},\cdots,a_{3n/4})$ and $\vec{a}^{(4)}=(a_{1+3n/4},a_{2+3n/4},\cdots,a_{n})$.

Comment: e.g. $\vec{a}=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ and $8/4=2$ and  $\vec{a}^{(1)}=(1,2)$, $\vec{a}^{(2)}=(3,4)$, $\vec{a}^{(3)}=(5,6)$ and $\vec{a}^{(4)}=(7,8)$ or $\vec{b}=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)$, $12/4=3$, $\vec{b}^{(1)}=(1,2,3)$, $\vec{b}^{(2)}=(4,5,6)$, $\vec{b}^{(3)}=(7,8,9)$, $\vec{b}^{(4)}=(10,11,12)$.

Comment: This looks like an [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.  Can you please explain *why* you want to chop up a vector like this?  What properties of vectors or matrices are you using to perform calculations?  What are you *actually* trying to do?  As an aside, I think that it would be better to write $b \in \mathbb{R}^{4N}$, so that the component vectors satisfy $b_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$&mdash;I think that this is much clearer notation.

Comment: For my work I am using the notation from [this publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/533715/), e.g. Eq. (9a). It's a window function/vector h(n) that ends up on diagonal and antidiagonal submatrices of a larger matrix. I thing this notation is good for introducing the notation, but verbose and cumbersome when deriving other variants of this matrix.